# Azuracast - Swagger API PHP Curl POST with API Key

Tags: curl, swagger

Hi new to REST APIs but I have a little exp in php and j/s hope to find some help and advise. AzuraCast is a SHOUTcast/Icecast auto dj panel, 100% open source and packed with features. They also have a nice API and I need help getting the remote start/stop/restart requests to work, I'm not sure how to authenticate.

Since i'm not really familiar with languages other then php/js I was working on using CURL but and unsure if this is a good choice, or exactly how to do it.

Here's the API demo page https://demo.azuracast.com/static/api/index.html

I did manage to get the GET calls working, but they are easy

and here is my code which would be to stop the server, it doesn't work but it's the closest I've gotten since it doesn't throw a error either :)

```
    $token = "b538f840ea9de018"; 
 function jwt_request($token, $post) {
       $ch = curl_init('https://demo.azuracast.com/static/api/station/1/frontend/stop');
       header('Content-Type: application/json');
       $post = json_encode($post);
       $authorization = "Authorization: Bearer ".$token;
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization ));
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
       $result = curl_exec($ch);
       curl_close($ch);
       return json_decode($result);
    }
```

Comment: sorry, I changed the $ch = curl_init to the demo but I did use my demo localhost and created the API key per their instructions, which is the b538f840ea9de018

Answer (score 1):

The proper base URI for making API calls is `your-azuracast-site.example.com/api/`, so in this case the full URI would be `https://demo.azuracast.com/api/station/1/frontend/stop`.

In the latest version of AzuraCast, visiting your API documentation on your installation will allow you to test the API calls directly with your own installation's API endpoints.